# iPhone APIs to access SMS, calendar, emails, call logs?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development, I am developing an application like sync for iPhone.

This application should read all databases like the address book, SMS, calendar, emails and call logs.

I have found an API to read the address book, however I couldn't find APIs to read SMS, calendar, emails, call logs or bookmarks.

How do I do it?

Comment: There are many applications that allow you to read sms and send them with emotion images as well. Examples: Textfree and Textnow iPhone applications. Did you find a way to accomplish what you started to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the address book and the photo library can be accessed from 3rd party iPhone apps.
If it's desperate, you could make it for jailbroken iPhones as *everything* is open then - but the app would only work on jailbroken phones (meaning no appstore and cydia is a pain)

Comment: How do i access  photo library  in i-Phone

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible due to the sandboxing on iPhone.

Comment: address book is all u get access to.  pray that apple doesn't restrict it further